# Facebook Graph API, v3.2 - How to get user media for an Instagram account (3.6.2019)?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram, media

I am working on Instagram API integration to our service. As of 3.6.2019, I have tried to get media for a particular Instagram user account. I have tried to understand the documentation, and this is what I have working so far:

- I have an Instagram business account
- I did attach my Instagram account to my business page by logging in
- I have obtained a page and a user access token via Graph API Explorer. User token has the following permissions:

> - email
> - instagram_basic
> - manage_pages
> - pages_show_list
> - pages_messaging
> - public_profile

- I am able to get information about the associated Instagram account like `profile_pic` and `username`.

What perplexes me about this is that when I read the documentation, user info retrieval  seems to work alright:

[image]

However, if I changed the URL to match the media retrieval URL and keeping the same user ID, I get the following error

[image]

even through the documentation says:

> To get all media objects on an Instagram Business User, send a GET request to the User's /media edge.

And the sample request URL provided:

```
GET graph.facebook.com/17841405822304914/media
```

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user/media/

What am I doing wrong? The URL seems to follow the documentation description. I did use the user access token for the media request. The access token contains permission for `instagram_basic`, as needed based on the documentation:

> **Permissions**
>
> An access token from the Instagram Business User, with the following
> permissions:
>
> - instagram_basic

I am using API version 3.2.

Comment: What kind of access token did you use, and what permissions did it include?

Comment: @04FS Added description of user access token permissions used.

Comment: Added more details in regards to permissions needed.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really use the right instagram id? Try calling this API with the ID you used:
`https://graph.facebook.com/v5.0/[ENTER_ID]?fields=instagram_business_account{id, username,profile_picture_url}&access_token={}`

I you get a result like this:

```
{
    "instagram_business_account": {
        "id": "XXXXXXX",
        "username": "XXXX",
        "profile_picture_url": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/44644278_733652060347074_11957"
    },
    "id": "XXXXXXX"
}
```

You know, that you used the wrong ID :D 
Go ahead and call the /media endpoint with the ID nested under instagram_business_account